# How do I Name a WP page in the New(ish) Block Editor?

Tags: pages, title

I'm building a custom theme and it's my first time doing this with the new(ish) block editor.

Can I ask - where on earth to add the page title in the backend block editor? In the old editor you just added it at the top of the page.

I've added a 'title' but this is just the h2 default title, not the page title/name.

Image-1 shows the page being nameless, Image-2 shows the H2 title.

[image]

[image]
Many thanks,

Emily

Comment: Hi - for some reason I don't know of the 'add title' link in the above wasn't clickable. I logged out of Chrome and went back in and then it was. There was clearly some type of bug in the system.

Comment: Yeah... I'm not a huge fan of the UI. I've been building stuff with WP for a long time, so maybe it's just bias, but IMHO the new editor is a bit confusing, especially when things like that happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click on "Add title" and it should bring up a text input.

Answer (score 2):

It's at the top. Write your title into "add title" then press "update" and the title is set.